# Parsing Groovy script from a restrictive project (tied to a framework/IDE)

Tags: parsing, groovy, classpath, katalon-studio

### Problem

I am in the process of porting a project from a Katalon Studio project (closed system), to a more standard Groovy project. Currently, I'm trying to build an automated tool that will parse my scripts and classes to provide changes to my structure and syntax. I'm having a lot of difficulty parsing the groovy scripts due to the fact that the files are not buildable from outside of Katalon Studio (if I import the project into something like IntelliJ IDEA, I can't build).

### Objective

The goal is to be able to parse the scripts somehow without the need for a custom parser (Groovy would make this pretty difficult, as it's syntactically lax).

### Summary of the Katalon Studio Project

It's set up like an Eclipse project. I have pasted the classpath below. The `.class` files are located in `bin/keyword`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/keyword" path="Keywords"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/listener" path="Test Listeners"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/lib" path="Libs"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/groovy" path="Include/scripts/groovy"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.core_1.0.0.202004070746.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Program%20Files/Katalon%20Studio/configuration/resources/apidocs/com.kms.katalon.core/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/aalto-xml-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.58.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.58.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/browsermob-core-2.1.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/cglib-3.2.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/commons-collections4-4.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/commons-validator-1.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/curvesapi-1.04.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/dnsjava-2.1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/java-client-7.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/jzlib-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/kat-server.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/littleproxy-1.1.0-beta-bmp-17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/mitm-2.1.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/netty-all-4.0.51.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/poi-3.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/proxy-vole-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/repackaged-sikuli-api-1.0.2-standalone.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/selenium-leg-rc-3.141.59.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/soap-builder-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/soap-common-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/soap-legacy-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/spring-context-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/stax2-api-4.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/testng-6.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/configuration/resources/lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/net.sf.supercsv.super-csv_2.1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.dom4j_1.6.1.v201312101416.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.commons.io_2.4.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.commons.lang_2.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.xmlbeans_2.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.google.gson_2.8.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.jsoup_1.7.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc4_4.1.5605.100.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.commons.dbutils_1.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.oracle.jdbc.ojdbc7_12.1.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.postgresql.jdbc41_9.4.1208.jre7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.3.v20170209-1843.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.constant_1.0.0.202004070746.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.eclipse.persistence.eclipselink_2.5.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.selenium-standalone_1.0.0.202004070746.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/atu.testrecorder.screen-recorder_2.1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.google.guava_23.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.util_1.0.0.202004070746.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.4.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpmime_4.5.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.commons.lang3_3.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.greenrobot.eventbus_3.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.assertj.core_3.10.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.junit_4.12.0.v201504281640/junit.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind_2.9.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core_2.9.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations_2.9.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/ch.qos.logback.classic_1.2.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/ch.qos.logback.core_1.2.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/slf4j.api_1.7.25.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.fusesource.jansi_1.17.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.netlightbody_1.0.0.202004070746.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.poi_1.0.0.202004070746.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/xml-apis_1.4.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.commons.commons-text_1.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.mysql.cj_8.0.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.proxyvole_1.0.0.202004070746.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.commons.codec_1.7.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.commons.logging_1.2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.beanshell.bsh_2.0.0.0b4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.ant.launcher_1.9.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.core.appium_1.0.0.202004070746.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.8.0.v20160509-1230.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.core.webui_1.0.0.202004070746.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Program%20Files/Katalon%20Studio/configuration/resources/apidocs/com.kms.katalon.core.webui/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.json_20140107.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.core.mobile_1.0.0.202004070746.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Program%20Files/Katalon%20Studio/configuration/resources/apidocs/com.kms.katalon.core.mobile/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/org.apache.commons.validator_1.5.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber_1.0.0.202004070746.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Program%20Files/Katalon%20Studio/configuration/resources/apidocs/com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/io.cucumber.core_3.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/io.cucumber.datatable_1.0.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/io.cucumber.datatable-dependencies_1.0.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/io.cucumber.expressions_5.0.19.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/io.cucumber.gherkin_5.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/io.cucumber.html_0.2.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/io.cucumber.java_3.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/io.cucumber.tag-expressions_1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/io.cucumber.junit_3.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.core.webservice_1.0.0.202004070746.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Program%20Files/Katalon%20Studio/configuration/resources/apidocs/com.kms.katalon.core.webservice/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/wsdl4j_1.6.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.google.oauth-client.google-oauth-client_1.22.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.google.http-client.google-http-client_1.22.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/ca.juliusdavies.not-yet-commons-ssl_0.3.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.preferences_1.0.0.202004070746.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Katalon Studio/plugins/com.kms.katalon.core.windows_1.0.0.202004070746.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Program%20Files/Katalon%20Studio/configuration/resources/apidocs/com.kms.katalon.core.windows/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/myUsername/git/myProj/Drivers/ashot-1.5.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/myUsername/git/myProj/Drivers/javax.mail.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/myUsername/git/myProj/Drivers/jcommon-1.0.23.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/myUsername/git/myProj/Drivers/jfreechart-1.5.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_SUPPORT"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

### (Failed) Attempts

I have tried using GroovyDocTool, GroovyClassLoader, GroovyShell by experimenting with the source code, but admittedly I have no idea what I'm doing, and there is very little documentation to go off of. What I ended up trying was a compilation of other answers on this site, and may not be correct.

What I tried (may be wrong):

Note - in Katalon, classes are referred to as "Keywords"

```
String[] sources =
                [
                        '/git/myProj/Keywords',
                        '/git/myProj/Scripts',
                ]
GroovyDocTool docTool = new GroovyDocTool(sources)
GroovyRootDoc rootDoc = docTool.getRootDoc()
println rootDoc.specifiedPackages()
println rootDoc.specifiedClasses()
for (GroovyPackageDoc p in rootDoc.classes()) {
    // This loop is never entered
    GroovyClassDoc[] allClasses = p.allClasses()
    for (GroovyClassDoc c in allClasses) {
        log(c.getFullPathName() + '\n')
    }
}
```

Output (all empty):

```
refactoringtool.script.ScriptParser.par  []
refactoringtool.script.ScriptParser.par  null
```

Attempts with GroovyClassLoader and GroovyShell are below. They run, but they can't get past the import statements.

```
File classDir = new File(baseDir + '/git/myProj/.classPath')
String classPath = classDir.toString()
println "classpath: ${classPath}"

File binDir = new File(baseDir + '/git/myProj/bin')
String binPath = binDir.toString()
println "binDir: ${binPath}"

File keywordDir = new File(baseDir + '/git/myProj/bin/keyword')
String keywordPath = keywordDir.toString()
println "keywordDir: ${keywordPath}"

GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader()
classLoader.addClasspath(classPath)
classLoader.addClasspath(binPath)
println "Added classpath:\n${classLoader.getClassPath()}"
println "Loaded classes:\n${classLoader.getLoadedClasses()*.getName()}"
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(classLoader)
Script script = shell.parse(fileText)
```

Exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class com.myClass
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import com.myClass
   ^
```

Comment: Eclipse IDE can give you a similar experience. Your .classpath file example should be directly usable in a Java/Groovy project in vanilla eclipse plus GDT and JDT. I would recommend starting with a small project to prove out Groovy scripts then add your sources and libraries.

Comment: https://forum.katalon.com/t/how-to-write-katalon-studio-tests-with-intellij-idea-and-other-ides/15940

Comment: @emilles unfortunately it does not work for some reason. I'm not sure exactly why though. I think it's an intentional lock from the creators of Katalon to keep the projects tied to their product. My heart tells me that there has to be some way to decouple it, but it doesn't look like I could find out how to do that exactly.

Comment: @daggett I have checked that post as well, and while it is useful for running one-off scripts, it still requires access to the original Katalon project to build, and does not fit my use case.

Thank you though! I have now decided to just put all of my eggs in the regex basket. Wish me luck! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

All listed attempts failed, but ended up building a script with a raw file parser that mapped out new->old syntax conversions and created new files with the converted content. Can be slow even when multithreaded, but it worked!